# Locating an seismic epicenter

Tags: earthquakes

I understand how to find an epicenter using three sensor locations and why three locations are needed.  Is it possible, though very improbable, to find an epicenter if you only have two seismic stations that are positioned in a way where the possible epicenter locations when drawn out in a circle only meet in one place?

Comment: The issue with two circles is that they always have two intersection points, so they would give two different locations to chose from. The third circle removes this ambiguity. I can see only one case where two circles would be enough: if they meet at a tangent, then they have only one point in common.